# jquery <video> .play not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, ios, html, video

I have a number of HTML5 `<video>` elements on my page, and all is working well on desktop. However, on iOS Safari, the  only plays upon a long hold on the video, rather than a normal tap (which should replicate the 'click' jquery function). Can anybody suggest why the video isn't playing upon tap? And why it does so after a short hold?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Preload the video
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.video video')[0].load();
  }, 0);

  $('.video video').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('is-playing')) {
      $(this).removeClass().addClass('is-paused');
      // Pause video
      $(this)[0].pause();
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass().addClass('is-playing');
      // Play video
      $(this)[0].play();
    }
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video src="video-url" poster="poster-url" preload></video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `touchstart` event with `on` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.video video')[0].load();
  }, 0);

  $('.video video').on('click touchstart', function() {
    // Change is here -------^
    if ($(this).hasClass('is-playing')) {
      $(this).removeClass().addClass('is-paused');
      $(this)[0].pause();
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass().addClass('is-playing');
      $(this)[0].play();
    }
    return false;
  });

});
```

### **[touchstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart)**

Comment: many thanks for the answer. That has helped and it does now work much better. However, it requires 2 touches, almost as if it is needing the user to be focused on the video before it will work?

Comment: Your welcome,  Unfortunately yes, this  problem caused by `OS` , more on `ios` no matter,`chrome` `safari` have this issue.