# video not playing on mobile when i tap on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

My html5 video is not playing on mobile whenever I tap on it. Everything works fine on desktop but not mobile. I need it to play whenever I tap on it and thats not happening.

This is my code

```
   $(document).on('mouseover', 'video', function() { 
        $(this).get(0).play();
        this.muted=true;
    }); 



    //pause video on mouse leave
    $(document).on('mouseleave', 'video', function() { 

        this.currentTime = 13;
        $(this).get(0).pause(); 

    });

    $(document).on('click', 'video', function() { 
        $(this).get(0).play();
        this.muted=false;
        this.currentTime = 0;

    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your html pls

Comment: In which device you are try to play it? Android mobile?

Comment: I am playing it on my iphone. But regardless if i'm playing on my iphone it should work on every mobile device whether it is and iphone or not, and i'm just afraid it will do that on other devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [touchstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart)

When you are using of a *Mobile Device* you need to set jQuery mobile touch event, already you are using `mouseover` or `click` so what? There is no click or mouse in there, so you should use `touchstart` event.

```
$(document).on('mouseover touchstart', 'video', function() {
```

And

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', 'video', function() {
```

*Just note that, in some case you need to touch twice!*

[jquery  .play not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47529918/4540183)

Answer (score 1):

Note sure in which devices you are try to play it. Here is my suggestion if you are on iphone. Add **playsinline** on video tag. Like -

```
<video autobuffer preload=auto playsinline autoplay loop muted style="min-width:100%; min-height:100%;" >
  <source type="video/mp4" src="//bg.cdn.ustudio.com/app/transcodes/TQAdh6DJdtuY.mp4">
  <source type="video/webm" src="//bg.cdn.ustudio.com/app/transcodes/TuX1xml2yZsS.webm">
</video>
```

Comment: I did that already look <video class="" id="cb" preload="auto"  style=" width: 45%; object-fit: cover; float:left; clear:both;
    height: auto; padding-left:2%;   margin-top:0px; border:2px solid white;  cursor:pointer; "><source  src="{{$proo->intro_video}}#t=13" playsinline alt="Video Unavailable"   id="" ></source>
  </video>

Comment: Oh. You are using angularjs to populate url?

Comment: Look at my ans and try

Comment: No angular i'm using something else. Its still not working. I don't want to keep you too long and its getting late. Thank you for taking the time out to help me.